# Consequences/impact after upgrading to Git 1.9 from Git 1.8.5.2 in Windows

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

Is there any consequence or impact after i upgrade Git from 1.8.5.2 to git 1.9 in a Windows Machine?

I have to change the version in a server using Windows OS used in Jenkins.

Does it affect something that will make git not work the same way as before?

Comment: why don't you go look at the 1.8.5.3 -> 1.9 changelogs and see if anything sounds like it would affect you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not see nay difference and no changes are required.

But if you upgrade to git v2.X there are many major changes which will need to be aware of.

### For example:

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When "git push [$there]" does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   "matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.